# Mudar Preposição de Acordo com Estado

Tags: php, wordpress, api

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Estou usando uma API de localização baseada no IP http://ip-api.com/

Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente. O que eu não consigo fazer é mudar o seguinte:

Olá visitante "de" São Paulo
Olá Visitante  "do" Rio de Janeiro

Tem como trocar essa preposição automaticamente de acordo com o estado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embora meio arcaico, funcionaria com *array:*

```
<?php
$uf = "São Paulo";
$preposicoes = array(
    "Rio de Janeiro" => "do",
    "São Paulo" => "de"); // complete com os demais estados

echo "Olá visitante " . $preposicoes[$uf] . " " . $uf . "!";
?>
```

Comment: Direto ao ponto.. Super correto! VLW man, que arcaico nada rs!

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa via `json` funcionou tranquilo aqui:

```js
            $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201",
                    context: document.body
                }).done(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#local-visitante").html(response.city);
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Olá visitante de <span id="local-visitante"></span></p>
```

Via PHP também funcionou ok seguindo as [especificações da documentação](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php):

```
<?php
    $ip = "177.33.22.36"; // the IP address to query
    $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    echo 'Olá visitante de: ' . $query['city'];
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei, mas repare que o usuário está perguntando outra coisa, não o que você respondeu...

Comment: Achei que ele queria exibir a cidade de forma dinâmica.